# Alternate ways to reduce execution time for bringing a POstgreSQL table to Pandas with 500000 rows?

Tags: python, postgresql, pandas, psql

I have a PostgreSQL DB with 70 tables of which I wish to access one specific table named "hub_psm_log_inter". I wish to bring it to pandas and apply some operations on it. The table I am accessing has a shape of (500000, 23), which will possibly increase in future. **It is taking around 3 minutes for psql.read_sql_query to execute.** **I wish to reduce the time its taking.** The rows which matter to me are where (cust_hub_id = 358 & status_switch = 1). Shape of df_on has only 10000 rows.

```
import numpy as np  
import pandas as pd  

import psycopg2 as pg  
import pandas.io.sql as psql

conn = pg.connect(
    database = '', 
    user = '', 
    password = '', 
    host = '', 
    port = '' 
)

df2 = psql.read_sql_query("SELECT * FROM hub_psm_log_inter", conn)


df4 = df2[df2.cust_hub_id == 358]
df4['status_switch'] = pd.to_numeric(df4['status_switch'], errors='coerce')
df_on = df4[df4.status_switch == 1]
```

Comment: I'm not an export on this but... just a thought: did you try to include your operation in the sql query?

Comment: Why not take your operation to the data, instead of bringing the data to your operation, i.e. perform a good old SQL query.

Comment: do you want to import all of the 500k lines or just the cust_hub_id==358 and status_switch==1?

Comment: just the cust_hub_id=358 and status_switch==1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `WHERE` clause in your SQL query:

```
SELECT * FROM hub_psm_log_inter WHERE cust_hub_id = 358 AND status_switch = 1
```

From the look of your code, `status_switch` may be stored as a string in your table, so you might need to quote it, i.e.

```
SELECT * FROM hub_psm_log_inter WHERE cust_hub_id = 358 AND status_switch = '1'
```

Comment: String formatting SQL queries and manual quoting etc. is error prone. Better to use [placeholders](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#the-problem-with-the-query-parameters) when passing values, and let the driver worry about such things. With `pandas.read_sql_query()` you'd use the `params` keyword argument along with driver dependent placeholders in the statement.